# Jquery .Change Function with If statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have another questions, as I am still new to javascript and jQuery. I am using Ajax to update a hidden field with a value. Ajax is sending back the correct Billing Domain (The state the service is offered) upon the selection of an office (which can have more than one office in a state).

Here is the jQuery that I am struggling with.

I am using this portion to make sure that the BillingDomainID1 Class is hidden or shown upon page load, Prior to a dropdown selection. This works well.

```
if($("#BillingDomainID").val() != 1){
        $(".BillingDomainID1").hide();
    } else {
        $(".BillingDomainID1").show();   
};
```

This part is where I am having the trouble. The getOfficeInfo part is flawless, as it does post the BillingDomainID value as it expected, but the If statement below requires that I click the OfficeID dropdown value twice before the If statement works. 
For the fun of it, I added an alert('hi') between the getOfficeInfo and the if statement and it made the if statement work. It almost seemed like the getOfficeInfo portion did not update the value fast enough for the if statement to work. What can I do to solve this?

```
    $("#OfficeID").change(function() {  

        getOfficeInfo($("#OfficeID").val(),$("#BillingDomainID")); 

        if ($('#BillingDomainID').val() != 1) {
            $('.BillingDomainID1').hide();
            return;
        } else {
            $('.BillingDomainID1').show()
        }

    });
```

Thank you all so much for your help!

Comment: In your line `getOfficeInfo($("#OfficeID").val(), $("#BillingDomainID"));` are you sure about `$("#BillingDomainID")`, maybe `$("#BillingDomainID").val()` is need no? @Kyle Logan Wray

Comment: you can try forcing a delay on the if statement, e.g. 200 ms: `setTimeout(function() { if ($('#BillingDomainID').val() ... }, 200);`

Comment: Hey guys, @simon, I have tried that before, but i saw no noticeable difference. I cannot be certain, but I am not sure if that is the issue in this very case.

Comment: @mjr, I tried what you suggested, and I come up with this,        $("#OfficeID").change(function() { 
            getOfficeInfo($("#OfficeID").val(),$("#BillingDomainID")); 
            setTimeout(function() { if ($('#BillingDomainID').val() != 1) {
                $('.BillingDomainID1').css('display', "none")}; 
            else {$('.BillingDomainID1').show()};
            }, 200);
           
        });     Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you mixed up some semicolons, but double check that and that's what I meant. Why, does it not do anything?

Comment: @mjr, I checked and it looks like I have it correct, but maybe you see something I don't?            
$("#OfficeID").change(function() { 
            getOfficeInfo($("#OfficeID").val(),$("#BillingDomainID")); 

            setTimeout(function() { if ($('#BillingDomainID').val() != 1) {
                $('.BillingDomainID1').css('display', "none")
            } else {
                $('.BillingDomainID1').show()
            }
            }, 200);
           
        });

Comment: That looks correct now, but try MJar's solution, it's more on the right track

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a suspicion but are you calling ajax inside the `getOfficeInfo` function?

If so, then most probably you make the call asynchronously, so it does not wait for the server response and the `if` statement executes too soon, before the value gets updated.

You should put this code

```
    if ($('#BillingDomainID').val() != 1) {
        $('.BillingDomainID1').hide();
        return;
    } else {
        $('.BillingDomainID1').show()
    }
```

inside the ajax on success handler.

So your `getOfficeInfo` function could look like this

```
function getOfficeInfo(OID, BDID) { 
    //alert(OID); 
    //alert(BDID); 
    $.post("/UserControls/getOfficeInfo.asp", {OfficeID: OID}, function(data) {
        BDID.val(data); 
        if (data != 1) {
            $('.BillingDomainID1').hide();
        } else {
            $('.BillingDomainID1').show()
        }
    }); 
    //alert(data);
}
```

The explanation for this change is that when you call `$.post(...)` this function return immediately, but the inner function `function(data) {...}` gets called after server responds to your request. So all the calls depending on the server response should be inside that function to be certain that you have the current data.

Comment: I am not familiar with what you telling me, so I would really appreciate an example if possible... here is the ajax function.     function getOfficeInfo(OID, BDID) {
        //alert(OID);
        //alert(BDID);
        $.post("/UserControls/getOfficeInfo.asp", {OfficeID: OID}, function(data) {
            BDID.val(data);
        });
        //alert(data);
    }

Comment: This was the answer to my problem. Thank you so much for the help!